# How to include an external dependency in a pipenv pipfile?

Tags: python, imagemagick, pipenv

I am using MoviePy for a program and to write text over the video I need ImageMagick installed. ImageMagick is not a python dependency, rather it is an external dependency. How can I include an ImageMagick download in my pipfile?

pipfile looks like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
moviepy = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

My program runs without issue if I manually install ImageMagick but I want it all to be self-contained like a normal pipenv virtual environment.

Comment: Managing non-Python dependencies isn't Pipenv's job (nor is it `pip`'s, or `poetry`'s, or `pip-tools`', or any other Python dependency manager's). Either install a pure Python library and depend on that, or handle this outside of Pipenv, e.g. by providing a compiled version / OS package or a `Dockerfile` or similar.

Comment: Another way of achieving that would be through the usage of Conda (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)